# AngularJS ng-controller not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I just now started learning on AngularJS from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp). I am trying to practice examples what ever they have mentioned in the tutorials. Every thing works fine but when i came to "AngularJS Controllers" it is not working properly as working well in [w3schools Try it Yourself »](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_controller). I ve forked my code into this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/santosh_patnala/dq8r196v/1/).
My script looks like this:

```
function personController($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
}
```

Try to help me out and suggest me a good tutorial(or any free pdf file).

Comment: man your code works fine just change the option in the fiddle from onload to "no wrap - in <head>" here is the changed option http://jsfiddle.net/dq8r196v/2/

Comment: yes it is fine in fiddle but not in my local machine. I am getting the following error:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'personController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Thanks for this question, I have the same problem when following another tutorial. I'm wondering was it a new version of AngularJS that required another syntax?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is your **[corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kutyel/dq8r196v/4/)**.

It is a good practice for angular that the controller definition must look something like this:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("personController", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

And, without doubt, the best tutorial ever for learning the *basics* of Angular is the ***[CodeSchool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js)*** one!

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah it works fine when i change my function into your angular.module code.
but what is the difference between these two functions..?

Comment: basically the syntax I used will allow you to pass more parameters to your controller in the future, like `$http` for example, and many others, which is very useful.

Answer (score 11):

It is a new approach. We cannot use controllers without a module no more. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018). Just add a module and append the controller then you will have no problem.

Comment: it seems you are right, but can you provide any resource for that . the link you provided does not mention anything written.

Comment: I pulled my hair out while debugging why it was working fine few weeks ago(1.2.x) and not working now (1.3.x) ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I just modified your js fiddle. Please check the [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dq8r196v/3/)

```
function personController($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
}
```

> There was no issue with your code except JS fiddle settings from **onLoad** to **No wrap - in head**

[image]

Comment: when i tried in my local machine I'm getting the following error. Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'personController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Hey @UiUx,Could you please post your local code including html and js so that I can help you better.

Comment: Thanks. It works, BTW in a new design of JS fiddle you need to set up this option in javascript area by in a drop down menu under (JavaSctipt+gear) button.

Answer (score 2):

by adding `np-app="myApp"` in any tag of html like **`<html ng-app = "myApp">`** my code works fine.

Comment: Thank you mate. Your answer + Kutyel's solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an application module, and then add a controller to it. In angular it is all about dependencies. Secondly you need an app-name.
The base tutorial is on their main page: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00
I started with it, and it worked fine with me. Just do all steps starting from step 1.

Comment: Their tutorial is very easy and you are learning by small steps. It will take you about 3 hours. Then you will have to search for a more advanced tutorials and start reading documentation:) Angular is very advanced.

Comment: Hi Beri thanks for your time and I m getting the error which I ve mentioned in above comment please find it and help me out

Answer (score 1):

This is a common search result for "Angular Controller Not Working" so I thought it'd be helpful to add the solution that fixed my "controller not working" problem.

I had my base route with `$routeProvider` pointing at a controller file and a templateUrl partial like so:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
    controller: 'homePage'
});
```

I had several other routes and all those controllers worked, but for some reason my first route wouldn't. Turns out, I had a small logic error in my partial and that prevented ANY of my controller code from running.

Dumb little mistake, but I was caught off guard that it was a logic issue in my partial that was preventing any controller code from running. It took a lot longer than I'd like to admit to find because the issue wasn't in my "JavaScript" even though the console errors were present. The joys of tightly coupled front-end code, amiright?

Answer (score 1):

You have to input function as a parameter inside module

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('personController',function($scope){
  $scope.firstName = 'John';
  $scope.lastName = 'Smith';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problrm may be if you will try to nest ngApp into anothe ngApp.

The documentation says:

`AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.`